# Need some more help with jQuery and textbox character count

Tags: jquery

I have the following code to count and trigger some functions using jQuery:

```
        jQuery('#input_guideName').keyup(function(e)
        {               
            if(this.value.length == 5)
            {
                jQuery("#guide_btnCreateGuide").css({'background-position':'top', 'cursor':'pointer'});
                jQuery("#guide_btnCreateGuide").bind('click', function() {
                    createNewGuide(); 
                });
            }
            else if(this.value.length < 5)
            {
                jQuery("#guide_btnCreateGuide").css({'background-position':'bottom', 'cursor':'default'});
                jQuery("#guide_btnCreateGuide").unbind('click');
            }
        });
```

Here are some issues I have encountered:

1. Using CTRL + V is counted as 2 keyup, and the code will run twice, executing the `createNewGuide()` twice. How can I avoid this?
2. Pasting code using right mouse button is not detected. How can I detect this? Bu putting a listener on RightMouseButton?
3. If I paste text > 5 characters, none of my functions are triggered. I cannot add a control on `if(this.value.length > 5)`, because then `createNewGuide();` will fire for each keyup.

Any ideas how I can overcome these issues?

**EDIT**
My "operational objective" is to create a new guide in DB and the guide name must be at least 5 characters long. The button for the 'create guide' will not be clickable unless name is at least 5 characters long.

Comment: Can you clarify your third issue?  What is your operational objective here?  Are you trying to provide UI feedback for anything that isn't exactly 5 characters long?  Is there a difference in what your application would do if the value were less than 5 characters versus more than 5 characters?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Handling Ctrl + V isn't as bad as you might think but handling paste in general is.  There's no `onpaste` event (at least not cross browser) and the middle/right click paste actually happens AFTER the `mouseup` event so if you just did `.bind('change keyup mouseup', func...` you'd miss it.  Given all that, I think a timeout is the best way to do this:

```
$(function() {
setTimeout(function() {
    var val = jQuery('#input_guideName').val();

    if (val.length > 5) {
        jQuery("#guide_btnCreateGuide")
          .css({'background-position':'top', 'cursor':'pointer'})
          .unbind('click')  // prevents duplicate click events
          .bind('click', function() {
                createNewGuide(); 
          });
    } else {
        jQuery("#guide_btnCreateGuide")
          .css({'background-position':'bottom', 'cursor':'default'})
          .unbind('click');
    }

}, 300);
});
```

Even in your original code, `createNewGuide()` wasn't being called on each keyup with `this.value > 5` but rather you were registering a new event on each keyup that call createNewGuide, so then on click, it would get called multiple times.

By doing `unbind` before `bind` prevents duplicate functions getting registered onclick, so you won't ever call `createNewGuide()` twice, even on ctrl + v;

You can tune the delay if you're worried about your users hitting the button quickly after shorting the input.

Comment: You're spot on. But when will you call `setTimeout()`?

Comment: Depends a little on your use case, but I'd say just wrap it in `$(function() { // code here })` so it starts as soon as the elements on the page have loaded.  Can't do it earlier than that, but if you had other requirements, you could start in on some other event trigger.

Comment: Oh no, the setTimeout is a builtin javascript function, not jquery.  It's actually window.setTimeout.

Comment: Bah... I give up. I'll just have the button enabled and to all the checking there. Not as sexy, but at least it'll work... :)

Comment: You just have a typo, its `setTimeout`, lower case `s`.

Answer (score 1):

I don't really get what all your code is good for and how it works exactly, but I think you need this:

```
var thereIsAGuid = false;
jQuery('#input_guideName').bind('keyup mouseup', function(e){
    if(this.value.length >= 5 && thereIsAGuid == false){
        jQuery("#guide_btnCreateGuide").css({'background-position':'top', 'cursor':'pointer'});
        jQuery("#guide_btnCreateGuide").bind('click', function() {
            createNewGuide();
            thereIsAGuid = true;
        });
    } else {
        jQuery("#guide_btnCreateGuide").css({'background-position':'bottom', 'cursor':'default'});
        jQuery("#guide_btnCreateGuide").unbind('click');
        thereIsAGuid = false;
    }
});
```

`keyup` and `mouseup` events are enough I think.

Comment: your code works. But I still have the problem that there is registered two keyup when I click CTRL + V, thus firing `createNewGuide();` twice.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of handling only KeyUp event, which is specific to keyboard events only you should consider binding to **Change** event also, that captures everything changed in the control?

Remember Chnage is a post event, so you must bind both

```
  $('#input_guideName').bind("change keyup", function() {
       //your code
  });
```

Comment: That will still not detect pasting code using right mousebutton